# Excel function to sum all actual costs plus estimates on blank rows with no calculation column

Tags: excel, if-statement, calculated-columns, vba

In Excel 2013, I need to sum all numbers in a column of actual costs plus estimates in a second column in rows where the actual costs are blank.

```
                   Estimate (A)    Actual (B)
     Row 1             106                  
     Row 2             212            230
     Row 3             318            295
     Row 4             424                
     totals            1060           525
```

I need to return 106 + 230 + 295 + 424.   (or 525 + 106 + 424)

What I have tried:

--I have solved the problem if I put a placeholder (like "missing") in the blanks and then using a SUMIF nested in a simple SUM. But that badly clutters the chart. 
          `=SUM(A5, SUMIF(B1:B4,"missing",A1:A4))`

--I have also solved the problem by creating a calculation column that has an ISBLANK function and then using the SUMIF over that result. However, I can't figure out how to consolidate. I realize I could create another sheet to hold the calculation column, but the workbook will already have a number of sheets and I want to avoid an extra. 
          `C1=ISBLANK(B1)` dragged down to C4 and then `=SUM(A5, SUMIF(C1:C4, "TRUE", A1:A4))`

--I have found a number of online descriptions of managing similar tasks with pivot tables and months, but I can't seem to figure it out for a simple table.

I think my ISBLANK attempt is failing on consolidation because of something to do with absolute references vs. ranges in the column, but I can't figure it out.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated--thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUMIF()` to sum all numbers in column A if the value to the right is blank. Then add the sum of column B.

See this formula:

```
=SUMIF(B:B, "", A:A) + SUM(B:B)
```

Comment: Thought too hard, this is a much better option.

Comment: @ScottCraner Didn't even notice your answer. I wouldn't say mine is "better" by any means. But thank you xD

Comment: It is better in that it avoids the array formula, and as such will be quicker.  Albeit, with it only being a one off formula, the user will never notice the difference, but one should strive to limit the use of array formulas if possible.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe all I was missing was using "" to indicate a blank. I have used "" to output a blank before, but never in an IF. Thank you so much for the quick, non-patronizing response!

Answer (score 1):

Use array version of SUM(IF()):

```
=SUM(IF(B1:B4<>"",B1:B4,A1:A4))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.